# Can't Install MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded mysql-installer-community-5.7.18.1.msi and want to create a mysql server and a command line client.

After my installation the only programs I have are mySQL installer and MySQL Notifier.

When I use installer to try to install the server it gives the error message below:

[image]

Comment: press yes .....

Comment: Then it doesn't install anything and doesn't tell me what the missing requirements are. I have made sure all requirements are installed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

I saw before I pressed next (before the error message) it said I didn't have "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013," I had 2015 so I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it and restarting.

I also tried making sure my Windows updates were all up to date.

Then realised as well as a next button before the error message there was also an execute. When I clicked that it installed the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013" components it wanted and seemed to work.